# how to detect mobile numbers in a string using javascript

Tags: javascript

To be honest, this sound like a duplicate post, but this is totally different from other post.

I'm building a chat room, where i would like to detect mobile number in user sending messages and warn the users that sending mobile numbers in the chat room is not safe and its against our policy.

There are few posts shows how to detect US number. But what about Indian numbers? they are 10 digit numbers.

```
var input = "hey im emily, call me now 9876543210"
```

I have to detect the number in all these formats.

> 9876543210
>
> 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
>
> 98765 43210
>
> +919876543210
>
> +91 9876543210

Some smart users always comes up with a smart way to come around those filters used in the client side javascript. So i have to be well prepared to detect all the method they use.

**Example Message :**

> "hey this is emy, call me now 9876543210"

Expected output : pop up saying, hey buddy, sending numbers in the room is not safe and not allowed here.

Note: The string message should be allowed to send upoto 5 digit numbers, without getting the alert pop up. Or if you have any better idea? suggest me and we can make it work. Thanks

Comment: You can use RegEx Pattern for detecting the phone number, As if your RegEx Pattern matches, then you ll get results accordingly

Comment: If someone wants to cheat, they cheat. You have virtually no possibility to detect every number. If I want to, I can still input a number as an image, or like `f3e3d39ee8` and tell the opposite how to read it.

Comment: The above solution is for the particular formats of number given by @MichealJose

Comment: ... If you really want to detect phone numbers, you need a well trained AI. A regex is like bringing a knife to a gun fight though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your test cases the length of phone number is `10`:

So try the following code:

```js
let input = "hey im emily, call me now 9 876543210";
let matched = input.match(/\d+/g).join('');
let phoneNumberLength = 10;
if (matched.length >= phoneNumberLength) {
  console.log(`we've found a phone number. The number is ${matched}`);
} else
  console.log(`The message does not contain phone number`);
```

Try to adjust this code as it is desired

**UPDATE:**

This code is intended to get desired results with test case by @tibetty:

```js
let input = 'hi dude, please call my cell phone +86 13601108486 at 300pm"'
let matched = input.split(' ');
let maxIndex = matched.length - 1;
let filtered = matched.filter((s, i) => {
  if (i != maxIndex && isNumeric(s) && isNumeric(matched[i + 1]))
    return true;
  if (isNumeric(s))
    return true;
  return false;
});
console.log(` The number is found ${filtered.join(' ')}`);

function isNumeric(n) {
  return n.match(/^(?:[+\d].*\d|\d)$/);
}
```

Comment: there's an apparent bug in your code when the input is a string like this: "hi dude, please call my cell phone +86 13601108486 at 300pm", so it's not a sound solution.

Comment: @tibetty thanks! Great catch! Please, see my updated answer!:)

Comment: Where is `isNumeric` defined?

Comment: in this case, i would like to use String.prototype.match() to detect digit sequences: s.replace(/ /g, '').match(/\d+/g).  However, to tell out the real number from the matched results, an regex matching and even more logic decision is inevitable.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a regex for a 7 or 10 digit number, with extensions allowed, delimiters are spaces, dashes, or periods:

`^(?:(?:\+?1\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?(?:\(\s*([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9])\s*\)|([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9]))\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-9]1|[2-9][02-9]{2})\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?([0-9]{4})(?:\s*(?:#|x\.?|ext\.?|extension)\s*(\d+))?$`

Although you need to add conditions for special numbers like 911, 100, 101

Answer (score 0):

try this one:
https://www.w3resource.com/javascript/form/phone-no-validation.php

```
function phonenumber(inputtxt)
{
  var phoneno = /^\d{10}$/;
  if((inputtxt.value.match(phoneno))
        {
      return true;
        }
      else
        {
        alert("message");
        return false;
        }
}
```

Comment: This won't detect more than half of the requirements

Comment: Does this cope with `+` and spaces?